# How to program a Ranked Set Sampling in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to program a ranked set sampling using `R`. There are **2*n^2** items and I want to randomly divide them into two equal sized groups with **n^2** items in each group. Then I want to use a Ranked Set Sampling from each of these groups to form **n** RSS blocks with **n** items in each RSS block.

What I was trying is shown below:

```
n<-4
id<-1:(2*n^2)
s1<-sample(id,n^2)
s2<-id[-s1]

block<-rep(1:(2*n),each=n)
d<-data.frame(block)
```

Now I want a column in my data frame named **rss** that will show which id's are selected in a particular RSS block.

I am not good at `R`. I was trying this:

```
for(i in 1:n){
d$rss<-ifelse(d$block==i,sample(s1,n),0)
#s1<-s1[-which(s1==d$rss)]
}

for(i in 1:n){
d$rss<-ifelse(d$block==i,sample(s2,n),0)
#s2<-s2[-which(s2==d$rss)]
}
```

which I know is very wrong! Can anyone help?

Comment: if `d <- data.frame( rss = block , s1 = s1 , s2 = s2 )` isn't what you want, can you provide your desired output?  :)

Comment: Yes, please manually create your desired output to show us what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give an example of the output you want, but giving it my best guess:

```
d <- transform(d,rss = ifelse(d[,"block"]<=n, sample(s1), sample(s2)))
```

Or, in a more organized manner:

```
d <- transform(d,block.id = rep(1:n))
d <- transform(d,rss = ifelse(d[,"block"]<=n, sample(s1), sample(s2)))

library(reshape2)
d <- dcast(d,block ~ block.id, value = rss)
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I was thinking it in a difficult way. You got it right. The first command is working perfectly. But my R cannot find any function named dcast. Do I have to call any library for that? I am using version 2.14.1.

Comment: Okay it is in reshape2 package. Thanks a lot!